# $_GET url slug instead of ID

Tags: php

I am rewriting a url, so instead of:

```
mysite.com/dealers.php?id=5
```

it is:

```
mysite.com/dealers/dealer-name
```

Instead of using $_GET['id'] and passing the ID, I am passing the slug i.e.: $_GET['slug']

I have the slug saved in the database but also have the record ID. I would feel more comfortable using the ID but just wanted to know if it is okay to use the slug or what is the best practice?

Comment: I believe that using a slug i more SEO friendly. Use what you think is better for your purposes.

Comment: Using the slug is totally fine, as long as the slug is unique in your database.

Comment: Great, thanks Magnus.

Comment: using slug can  give you multiple records (depends on db) , while `id` will give you single-record only

Comment: @AlivetoDie I wouldn't say that it _will_ give him multiple records. It totally depends on the database.

Comment: check `.htaccess` URL Rewrite if you're using apache